# rsync --update with symlinks

Tags: rsync, symlink

This is related to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333292/220834) but I don't think the answer exactly applies here.

I have two servers that sync directories between each other. These directories contain files and symlinks. On server *B*, I sync from server *A* with this command: `rsync -auv A:dir/ dir/`

**What I want**: Any file or symlink on *A* that is different and newer than the corresponding file or symlink on *B* is synced.

**What actually happens**: Any file on *A* that is different and newer than the corresponding file on *B* is synced. Any symlink on *A* that is different than the corresponding symlink on *B* is synced, *regardless of timestamp*.

The man page for `rsync` has this (emphasis mine):

> -u, --update
>
> This forces rsync to skip any files which exist on the destination and have a modified time that is newer than the source file. (If an existing destination file has a modification time equal to the source file's, it will be updated if the sizes are different.) **Note that this does not affect the copying of symlinks or other special files.**

So this is the expected behavior. Why is this? Is there a way around it? Or, is there an alternate solution to the overall goal, which is to get these directories in sync after a server has been offline for some time and missed data?

My rsync version is `3.0.9`.

**Example**: I set up 2 directories, `Adir` and `Bdir`, each containing a file and a symlink with different contents:

```
$ ls -l Adir/ Bdir/
Adir/:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kevin kevin  5 May 27 18:00 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kevin kevin 10 May 27 18:00 symlink -> /some/file

Bdir/:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kevin kevin  6 May 27 17:00 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kevin kevin 16 May 27 17:00 symlink -> /some/other/file
```

Running `rsync --dry-run -auv Adir/ Bdir/` outputs this:

```
sending incremental file list
./
file
symlink -> /some/file

sent 101 bytes  received 21 bytes  244.00 bytes/sec
total size is 15  speedup is 0.12 (DRY RUN)
```

Which is what I expect. It copies (or would if not in dry run) both the file and symlink because they are newer. However running `rsync --dry-run -auv Bdir/ Adir/` outputs this:

```
sending incremental file list
./
symlink -> /some/other/file

sent 104 bytes  received 18 bytes  244.00 bytes/sec
total size is 22  speedup is 0.18 (DRY RUN)
```

Even though `Bdir/symlink` is older than `Adir/symlink` it still gets syned.

Comment: "_the overall goal, which is to get these directories in sync after a server has been offline for some time and missed data_" - do you want to get B to look like A, or A to look like B? Either way, I don't understand why the fact that the reverse operation doesn't work is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way out may be to ignore symlinks in rsync and do them separately with, for example, `tar` which can be asked not to overwrite newer targets. Eg

```
( cd Adir; find . -type l |
  tar cf - -T- 
) |
tar xvvf - --keep-newer-files -C Bdir
```

Comment: This sounds like it would be a messy solution because the directories are on different servers. But I could probably work with this is there aren't any better options.

Comment: I was also looking for a cleaner, solution, but in the edn just chaining tar, with ssh, seems to work ok `cd / ; ssh remote tar -cz /var/folder | tar -xz --keep-newer-files`. Its inneffient that transfers all data over the 'wire' even if not ultimatly extracted. A slight hack is to perhaps look for the newest file on local (ie when last run) and then just add '--after-date ' to the first tar, to only tranfer new files more incrementally - still not as effient as rsync.